# What does template's implicit specialization mean?

Tags: c++, templates

In the chapter `N3797::14/4 [temp]` (emphasis mine)

> A template name has linkage (3.5). A non-member function template can
>   have internal linkage; any other template name shall have external
>   linkage. Specializations (explicit or *implicit*) of a template that
>   has internal linkage are distinct from all specializations in other
>   translation units.

was mentioned about implicit specialization. As far as I understand from the context, that concept is different from the template explicit specialization which has

`template < >` *declaration*

grammar. So, I'm guessing that implicit specialization has something to do with a partial class template specialization. Unfortunately, I couldn't normative reference defining the implicit specialization concept in the current working draft.

Comment: Surely it just means all specializations other than explicit ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no normative term called "implicit specialization".
However, I believe that in this context, it means the complement of "explicit specialization": Every specialization that was not explicitly specialized by the user, in other (normative) words, **instantiated specializations**.
Consider that there are

- Explicit specializations
- Implicit instantiations
- Explicit instantiations

Specializations instantiated through the latter two one could refer to as "implicit specializations".

Comment: Well, if we apply explicit specialization to a template will the coresponding class/function definition be put into a compiled object file?

Comment: Just to clarafy, I think if we apply a partial specialization for a class template, any class definition won't be put into an object file unless it's instantiated (implcitly/ explcitily). Am i right?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv A partial specialization is a template, and if it isn't instantiated, then it will remain as effectless with respect to the program as uninstantiated primary templates are.

Answer (score 0):

The term isn't used much in the Standard, but we can deduce what it means from §14.5.5.3 - reproduced below - which I've broken into paragraphs (A), (B) and (C) for ease of reference (boldfacing mine):

> (A) If a member template of a class template is partially specialized, the member template partial specializations are member templates of the enclosing class template; if the enclosing class template is instantiated (14.7.1, 14.7.2), a declaration for every member template partial specialization is also instantiated as part of creating the members of the class template specialization.
>
> (B) If the primary member template is explicitly specialized for a given **(implicit) specialization** of the enclosing class template, the partial specializations of the member template are ignored for this specialization of the enclosing class template.
>
> (C) If a partial specialization of the member template is explicitly specialized for a given **(implicit) specialization** of the enclosing class template, the primary member template and its other partial specializations are still considered for this specialization of the enclosing class template. [ Example:

```
template<class T> struct A {
    template<class T2> struct B {}; // #1
    template<class T2> struct B<T2*> {}; // #2
};
template<> template<class T2> struct A<short>::B {}; // #3

A<char>::B<int*> abcip; // uses #2
A<short>::B<int*> absip; // uses #3
A<char>::B<int> abci; // uses #1
```

> -- end example]

Repeating (B) with my cross-references to the example in parentheses:

> *"if the primary member template* (i.e. #1) *is explicitly specialised (as at #3) for a given (implicit) specialisation of the enclosing class template* (`A`)*, the partial specialisations of the member template* (#2) *are ignored for this specialisation of the enclosing class template*".

We see the specialisation  at #3 results in the ignoring of #2 for `absip;`.  We can therefore conclude that the following line...

```
template<> template<class T2> struct A<short>::B {}; // #3
```

...performs an implicit specialisation of the enclosing class template, namely `A<short>`.

So, ***implicit specialisation*** is when specialisation of a member function implicitly involves specialisation of the class template that it's a member of.  Put another way, the class template `A` didn't require a separate earlier specialisation for `short` before the member template at #1 was specialised, because it could be specialised implicitly.

Comment: I thought it's called a template argument deduction, not an implicit specialization.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some normative reference describing that?

Comment: @MattMcNabb *(Template) Argument deduction.

Comment: *"when specialisation of a member function"* - for a record - a **member template** in general (a function member, a class member or a static data member, the above section is about class members though).